# get table does not exist in mysql after adding new hard disk

Tags: mysql

I have added a new hard disk to my VM where my mysql server were located on. Suddenly, mysql returns `table does not exist` for all my databases; even though I can see all tables with `show tables` command.

```
mysql> use mydb;
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_mydb        |
+-----------------------+
| mytable               |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist

mysql> select * from mydb.mytable;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist
```

I have tried to restore tables with solutions provided [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html):

*Using `mysqlcheck --repair`:*

```
root@mylab:/var/lib/mysql# mysqlcheck -umyuser -pmypass --repair -- 
databases mydb
mydb.mytable
Error    : Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
```

*Using `REPAIR TABLE`:*

```
mysql> use mydb;
mysql> REPAIR TABLE mytable;
+---------------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Table                     | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                        |
+---------------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| mydb.mytable              | repair | Error    | Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist              |
| mydb.mytable              | repair | status   | Operation failed                                |
+---------------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Using `ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;`:*

```
mysql> use mydb;
mysql> ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE = InnoDB;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist
```

*Using `mysqldump`:*

```
root@mylab:/var/lib/mysql# mysqldump -umyuser -pmypass mydb > /root/mydb.sql
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

I have tried repairing with [these solutions](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/repairing-mysql-databases-and-tables). Since `mysqlcheck` had failed before, I tried `myisamchk` for all files starting with `mytable` in `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/`; the command output was `is not a MyISAM-table` for all of them.

**EDIT 1:**

I checked database management files in `/var/lib/mysql/` which is set as `datadir` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`; all of them were listed there:

```
root@lab-188:/var/lib/mysql# ls -lat | grep ib
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  5242880 May 24 12:22 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 18874368 May 24 12:22 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  5242880 May 24 11:08 ib_logfile1
```

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried following solutions:

***Restart `mysql` service:***

Still get the same error.

***Fix `mysql` directory's permissions:***

```
chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

Nothing changed.

***Try loading database files in another server:***

I copied the whole directory of database, `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/`, to another server which has `mysql` too, restarted `mysql` there and logged in to it.

The database was shown there, but selecting content of its tables returned same error as previous server:

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist
```

**EDIT 3:**

Another solution which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should), was to disble/enable `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` which didn't help in my case:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: In your config file `my.cnf`, check if `datadir=/var/lib/mysql/`. Your `ib` files should be in the root of the datadir

Comment: @ThomasG, yes; those files are listed there as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I checked again and I don't see any `datadir` reference  in your question. My comment is thus still valid : which folder is specified as `datadir` in your config file ?

Comment: @ThomasG, you said *`ib` files should be in the root of datadir*; you never asked me to tell you what is my `datadir`. I mentioned in the question *I checked database management files in /var/lib/mysql/; all of them were listed there*; please search the sentence to find what I told about `ib` files.

Comment: Ok read my first comment again, the very first sentence. You seem to not understand and it is clear enough

Comment: @ThomasG, I really appreciate you trying to help. I think we both are talking about the same thing. In the question, I am clearly telling everyone that `ib` files are listed in `/var/lib/mysql/`and if it helps you to get out of your loop, yes, I have the line `datadir=/var/lib/mysql/` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`; I will add it to the question though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move InnoDB tables around by moving files.  There is critical info in `ibdata1` that you lose by simply moving `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/`.

Nor does it work for a database, such as `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/`.

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful; but unfortunately it's not answering the question.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar - You can move all of `/var/lib/mysql/`, but not one database (`mydb/`) in it.

Comment: Yes, I got what you said; but it's currently impossible for me. I have a lot of data files; moving them to another server/directory consumes a lot of time and needs a lot of spare hard disk.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar - At this point, what is the goal?  (1) Move tables around on the same server? Or (2) Recover table(s) that were 'lost' by a failed attempt to do #1?

Comment: I hope I can find a way to do the second one.